# Математические формулы LaTeX

Tags: поддержка, редактор

Нигде в справке не нашел информацию о том, как вводить математические формулы, используя синтаксис LaTeX. Иногда перед созданием алгоритма нужна математическая постановка задачи кроме копирования кода, и LaTeX очень нужен.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду на сайте? Тогда, возможно, ваш вопрос на самом деле на Мету.

Comment: Да, хотелось бы на СО вводить формулы. Есть интересные задачи из алгеброгеометрической теории кодирования, которые относятся к ИТ.

Comment: Может, смигрировать его таки на Мету? Там на него ответит Николас.

Comment: Там мое сообщение не нравится автоматическому чекеру. Похоже, что он требует в сообщение налить воды, чтобы было солидно.

Comment: Это вроде уже обсуждалось на Мете главного SO. Решили, что этот функционал слишком сильно замедляет страницы.

Answer (score 8):

В принципе, вставить формулу используя MathJax можно — как "фрагмент кода на JavaScript", [см. здесь](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283127). Привожу пример:

```html
<script src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script> <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts:["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk:(MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) }, tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"]], displayMath: [["$$","$$"]], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" }, TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, Macros: { href: "{}" } }, messageStyle: "none" });   </script>

$$ \Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt $$
```

Этот подход не очень удобен, так что на практике вставить формулу в виде изображения проще.  К примеру, используя http://latex2png.com/?latex=%5CGamma%28z%29+%3D+%5Cint_0%5E%5Cinfty+t%5E%7Bz-1%7De%5E%7B-t%7Ddt&res=600&color=000000&x=59&y=26

[image: \Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt]

после генерации картинки, скопируйте её ссылку (в меню по щелчку правой кнопки мышки) и вставьте в сообщение (<kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>).

Comment: Как же ужасно оно дважды прыгает...

Answer (score 4):

Мда.. расширение MathJax тут не работает. Хотя на математическом разделе stackexchange прекрасно всё отображается. https://math.stackexchange.com/

```
$$
\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\,.
$$
```

Может стоит обратиться к админам для расширения функционала?

Comment: MathJax — достаточно тяжёлая библиотека, и на подсайтах, на которых математика практически не применяется, её вряд ли будут подключать.

Comment: Ещё работает на http://mathoverflow.net Но сочетание MathJax и проограммирования - неподъёмно

Answer (score 4):

Можно добавлять формулу в виде картинки.

Или в виде программной записи этой формулы.

Comment: А кстати, это может быть идея для юзерскрипта?

Comment: @VladD, и что же должен делать этот скрипт?

Comment: Ну, пусть скрипт добавит кнопку в инструменты редактирования вопроса/ответа, по нажатию которой откроет окно, подгрузит в него mathjax, пользователь введёт латеховскую формулу (с предпросмотром), и по нажатию кнопки «вставить» сгенерирует из mathjax'овской формулы картинку, загрузит ей на imgur и вставит в редактор.

Comment: @VladD, а не жирно ли? Не так уж часто формулы нужны.

Comment: Жирно в смысле, что много работы? Ну да, есть такое. Но вроде ж ничего нереального? Тем более, кому не нужно, тот и не будет ставить себе скрипт.

Comment: @VladD, я про написание скрипта. Ничего нереального действительно нет (наверное), но и ничего особо простого нет...

Comment: Ну, реально непонятная часть — это автогенерация картинки, всё остальное, по идее, должно быть тривиально. Но это я говорю не умея работать с html/js, возможно, всё на самом деле куда сложнее. Редактор формул с предпросмотром реализован же на math.SE, можно стащить оттуда. Наверняка есть в официальных примерах на mathjax.