# Использование формул в ответах (поддержка TeX)

Tags: предложение

А насколько сложно добавить поддержку формул TeX в ответах? Все-таки бывает нужно пояснить понятнее, чем `sqrt(2*pi*x^(n+2))` - а чтоб выдать [image: введите сюда описание изображения], приходится лезть куда-то типа на mathurl, вводить, копировать, вставлять как картинку...

Может, имеет смысл добавить эту поддержку непосредственно на сайте?

Comment: В принципе, в движке должна быть реализация TeX - на math.so же живут как-то.

Comment: @vp_arth Как говорится, об том и спич... Что это вроде бы *уже есть*, так почему бы его не включить? :)

Comment: Как выглядит справка у них по редактированию постов: https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex

Comment: @Андрей Ну, пробуем... $\sqrt{x^2}$... Не получается. Тогда не понял, к чему эта справка (я думал, вы намекаете, что у нас это **уже** работает, просто мы не знаем...)

Comment: @Harry, сомневаюсь что поддерживается в комментариях, хотя, у нас и в сообщениях не поддерживается, надо, значит, чтоб включили...

Comment: можно и без mathurl и копирования картинки, а вставить ссылку на картинку напрямую в сообщение, [используя google chart api](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76905/359876)

Comment: @diraria Не сказал бы, что это легче...

Comment: На physics.so есть такая возможность, tex работает

Comment: А зачем оно нам?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вообще-то программирование - это не только кодирование, но очень часто еще и математическая постановка задачи, и ее решение...

Comment: @Harry, скорее редко, чем часто, а формулы можно и так написать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да и код без форматирования тоже можно... Компилятор поймет :) Но мы же от него не отказываемся?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вообще TeX не сошелся лишь на использовании формул. Это и таблицы, и графы, автоматы, рисунки, необычное форматирование... И потом, посмотрите книги Д.Кнута - их материал явно имеет отношение к SO, и ни строчки кода (почти). Обсуждать что-то оттуда лично мне бы хотелось на SO, а вот аккуратно оформить вопрос без TeX - уже трудности.

Comment: @Jenssen, сумма и без TeX'а: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/740500/178988

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1661/178988

Answer (score 4):

Подобное предложение было озвучено уже несколько раз. Например, на MSE: [LaTeX on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30559/339911) и enSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252282/3240681. В обоих случаях был получен отказ.

Причины такие:

- нужна математика — идите на math.SE и mathoverflow;
- страница грузится дольше на 20%, даже если формулы не используются на ней;
- можно использовать юникод и теги типа `sup/sub`, этого бывает достаточно;
- требуется не так часто для тематических сообщений;
- может ломаться уже существующий рендеринг.

В качестве альтернативы предлагается вставлять картинкой, полученной из стороннего сервиса.

С точки зрения потери производительности для ruSO было бы наверное не так существенно, как для enSO из-за другого объема посещений. Но мне кажется сомнительным, что на локализованных версиях SO будет больше функционала, нежели на основном сайте.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, иначе как отмазки, эти резоны не воспринимаются.

Comment: @Harry мопед не мой :)

Comment: на ресурсы на английском зачем посылать? зачем вообще тогда сайт на русском?¶ Трафик здесь пренебрежим по сравнению с большим SO. На клиенте, после первой загрузки, разницы особой не должно быть ([можно экспериментально убедиться с помощью snippet и mathjax](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1668/23044))¶ TeX помогает с представлением информации. Большинство посетителей вероятно и не заметят, но опытным участникам может быть удобно. Не стоит нормы большого SO слепо переносить, масштабы здесь другие.

Comment: @jfs а кто посылает на английский?

Comment: ответ буквально содержит "идите на"

Comment: @jfs может быть это недостаточно очевидно, но перечень причин — это сводный список, из-за чего FR получил статус declined на MSE и MSO.